# already defines a member called with the same parameter types c#

Tags: c#

Just as title says i have this error `already defines a member called with the same parameter types c#`

I have looked into multiple same questions but they all tells why does it happens and how to deal with it (change name of method to some other) BUT i do not want to change method name to something other because it is same method but with different parameter so i just want to bypass it.

Here are 2 methods i have:

```
public static List<int> Lista(int vrDok)
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    using (FbConnection con = new FbConnection(M.Baza.connectionKomercijalno2018))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("SELECT BRDOK FROM DOKUMENT WHERE VRDOK = @VrDok ORDER BY DATUM ASC", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VrDok", vrDok);

            FbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                list.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]));
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
public static List<int> Lista(int magacinId)
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    using (FbConnection con = new FbConnection(M.Baza.connectionKomercijalno2018))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("SELECT BRDOK FROM DOKUMENT WHERE MAGACINID = @MID ORDER BY DATUM ASC", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MID", magacinId);

            FbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                list.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]));
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

So as you can see they are totally identical but with different parameter and it drops me error.

How can i bypass it?

Comment: Try and see it from the compiler's point of view. If I wrote `Lista(1)`, how would it know which one to call? How does it know that 1 is a magacinId or a vrDoK?

Comment: Those methods only differ in the parameter names, not the parameter types.

Comment: Then what is smartest thing to do to different them?

Comment: `ListaByMagacin` and `ListaByVrDok` would be one example (but I'm obviously mixing languages there)

Comment: So it is not smart to make it with same name and somehow different by var name

Comment: It's not about smart or not, it's simply not possible to declare two methods with the same name and signature only differing in parameter names.

Comment: unrelated, but suggestion to improve your coding happiness: "Dapper" - `using(var con = /* create etc */) { return con.Query<int>("SELECT BRDOK FROM DOKUMENT WHERE MAGACINID = @MID ORDER BY DATUM ASC", new { MID = magacinId} ).AsList(); }` - and **that's it** - nothing more, not even a `con.Open()` - yet it does "all the right things" in terms of doing everything efficiently and correctly. It deals with the parameters, the reader, all that stuff - so you don't have to. Plus it will load columns of data into POCOs, value-tuples, etc. Example: you've missed a `using` in 2 places. Dapper won't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any of Davide suggestions will work. Another options is to do just have one method that takes the ID and the Parameter Name like so:

```
public static List<int> Lista(int id,string paramName)
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    using (FbConnection con = new FbConnection(M.Baza.connectionKomercijalno2018))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("SELECT BRDOK FROM DOKUMENT WHERE MAGACINID = @MID ORDER BY DATUM ASC", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, id);

            FbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                list.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]));
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Since everything in both methods are the same and just which parameter name changes.

Comment: Probably it would be best to introduce an `enum` rather than a `string`.

Comment: @Enigmativity yeah that is an option. I figured a string would give the most flexibility and less change.

Comment: Is right but becomes poorly upgradable. If the name of the parameter in the db were change, all the occurrences would have to change.

Comment: @DavidePizzolato - Yes, that's part of the point. You should be forced to think of the database and code as one system and you have to manage the references in each. That's better than hoping some programmer doesn't accidently typ th rong think.

Comment: I will use this approach but with `enum` instead of `string`

Comment: If you want to do this you need to update the sql string as well to actually refer to the correct parameter in its where clause. There is not much point in making the actual name of the parameter itself change - you might as well just call that "@id" or something generic.

Answer (score 7):

**It gives error because the method signature is the same**

- Lista(int)
- Lista(int)

The parameters name doesn't matter only the method name and the parameters type are considered.

You can resolve by changing the name of one method (ex. ListaByVrDok, ListaByMagician)

Comment: It is worth noting in your first section that the "return List" is not relevant. You can't have a method that differs only by return type so the important thing is just the `Lista(int)`.

Comment: @Chris IIRC *at the IL level* you can, but at the C# level - indeed you can't author or consume such methods.

Comment: "Change int [to] double in one method" is hardly a good approach. It's probably a bad idea.